# gcc: how to ONLY show #warning (-Wcpp) type warnings through gcc flags

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning, compiler-flags

I'm trying to compile a large C file with many `#warning` embedded in several places in the file. When I compile my file I want only those warnings to be shown. However, it seems that through the gcc flags I can either suppress all warnings (`-w`), or disable warning types one by one and keep `-Wcpp` to show the #warnings. Is there a way to show only -Wcpp type warnings without disabling the other warning types individually?

I am using arm-none-eabi-gcc version 4.9.3 on a Windows platform.

Comment: grep for `#warning` (that is, grep gcc's output)?